# RemoteCommand is not called in javaScript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

After a button is clicked a message is shown after 3 seconds, but when i try to call a function instead of message then it doesn't do anything? what is reason? thanks

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
     <p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandName"
            actionListener="#{uploadManagedBean.delayTime()}" />
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){  remoteCommandName()}, 3000);  ----> here the problem: when alert("hello") instead of remoteCommandName() it works but when i try to call the remoteCommandName() it doesn't
}
</script>
```

Hint: if i change the attribute in remoteCommand from actionListner to onStart, then when i load the page the methode uploadManagedBean.delayTime() will directely called without click on a button and without any delay.

Comment: Present please minimal reproducible example in codesandbox or something like this

Comment: here you can finde the code: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout

Comment: But you are using jsf

Comment: Yes, therefore i used remoteCommand. I need to use  jsf.

Comment: Anyhow, based on your previous questions this seems to be an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Maybe someone faces the same problem (here and there) with two different approaches  @Jasper de Vries

Comment: A number of things can be causing this behavior. Please show the definition of the full page.

Comment: Review if you have the remotecommand inside a form or try onclick = remoteCommandName() to verify that it works